# For how many attacks is a creature flat footed when attacking from concealment?

Tags: rogue, pathfinder-2e, sneak-attack, concealment, flat-footed

I am behind a tree (considered hidden) and attack my enemie. According to the rules he is considered flat footed.

```
Hidden: ... you’re flat-footed to a hidden creature
```

further

```
Sneak Attack: When your enemy can’t properly defend itself, you take advantage to deal extra damage. If you Strike a creature that has the flat-footed condition with an agile or finesse melee weapon, an agile or finesse unarmed attack, or a ranged weapon attack, you deal an extra 1d6 precision damage.
```

But I cannot find a hint whether the creature is flat footed to all attacks I can make within a round (so 3) or only to the first. In which case I would have to use e.g. Twin Feint for the second attack.

Comment: about formatting: 4 spaces are for code, not quotes. Please use ">" instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### In this case, target would only be flat-footed for the first attack.

The rule you're looking for is under the [Hide](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=62) action, specifically this sentence:

> If you attempt to Strike a creature, the creature remains flat-footed against that attack, and you then become observed.

If you were to remain Hidden for your entire turn (such as by being affected by a heightened [Invisibility](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=164) spell), they'd be flat-footed for every attack, but in this case, the Hidden condition ends after the first Strike.